# Fatal error when adding product to cart in PrestaShop

Tags: php, prestashop

I wont add product to cart in prestashop 1.7 but When i execute code below, i return Fatal error but in other card in browser i refresh cart and have the product, attribute and quantity what adding in code. So whats the problem with code, work well but return fatal error

```
require_once('config/config.inc.php');
require_once('classes/Cart.php');

function addProductToCart($id, $productAttributeID)
{
    $context = Context::getContext();
    $id_cart = $context->cookie->__get('id_cart');

    $cart = new Cart($id_cart);

    $cart->updateQty(1, (int)$id, (int)$productAttributeID);
    $cart->update();

    Tools::redirect('order');

}

addProductToCart(41, 518);
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught PrestaShopException: Błąd krytyczny in
> /home/symon/php/39/pet-food-shop/classes/Tools.php:1109 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 /home/symon/php/39/pet-food-shop/classes/Product.php(3153): ToolsCore::displayError() #1
>
> /home/symon/php/39/pet-food-shop/classes/Product.php(4741):
> ProductCore::getPriceStatic(41, false, 518, 6, NULL, false, true, 1)
>
> ## 2 /home/symon/php/39/pet-food-shop/classes/Cart.php(811): ProductCore::getProductProperties(1, Array) #3
>
> /home/symon/php/39/pet-food-shop/classes/Cart.php(1456):
> CartCore->getProducts(true) #4
> /home/symon/php/39/pet-food-shop/addProductToCart.php(17):
> CartCore->updateQty(1, 41, 518) #5
> /home/symon/php/39/pet-food-shop/addProductToCart.php(34):
> addProductToCart(41, 518) #6 {main} thrown in
> /home/symon/php/39/pet-food-shop/classes/Tools.php on line 1109

Comment: Catch the exception and continue on if you understand the reason it is raised and can simply ignore it? Otherwise, template/theming issue perhaps?

Comment: unfortunately, i cant ignore this, because i dont know how the system will react in the future at the customer server

Comment: Are you migrating from an older version of PrestaShop? https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues/13909

Comment: thanks to reply, I think "we" haven't migrated from the older version, but i need check this and my DB, what prefer in this thread

Comment: unfortunately, still dont work...

Answer (score 0):

Your script is not a part of prestashop (module or override), so prestashop context does not work properly. You should include init.php also.
Then prestashop context works with frontend context, then product price works fine.

```
<?php

require_once 'config/config.inc.php';
require_once 'init.php';
```